# picinpars and ragged2e appear to create a capacity exceeded error when switching alignment

Tags: errors, ragged2e, picinpar

I have an odd issue that appears to stem from the ragged2e package. I need to be able to have an image shown on the right with right aligned wrapped text around it. However, when I have to switch the alignment, it is causing a stack error. Without the alignment change, it works correctly.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\\->\ifhmode \unskip \else \@nolnerr \fi \par 
                                          \@ifstar {\nobreak \@xcentercr...
l.11 ...dLeft نلي بلانت السياحي. \\
                                              [\baselineskip]
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13893 strings out of 493734
 287245 string characters out of 6146347
 328326 words of memory out of 5000000
 17181 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3696 words of font info for 21 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,11n,39p,10385b,271s stack positions out of
 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 No pages of output.
```

The MWE or rather broken example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,demo]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\begin{tabwindow}[0,r,{\begin{tabular}[t]{r}\includegraphics[width=0.28
\textwidth]{bob}\\
\end{tabular}},{ \ }] \RaggedLeft نلي بلانت السياحي. \\[\baselineskip]
\end{tabwindow}\end{document}
```

Of note the image 'bob' is simply a random image I found online, and found any image would create the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of `ragged2e`. I'm trying to analyze the problem.

First: The latest version of `picinpar` is from 1993-07-13 - so it predates LaTeX2e. And IMHO it is a hack.

The cause of the problem seems to be that `picinpar` redefines `\par` to `\\` - and `ragged2e` changes the semantics of `\\` so that it calls `\par` (it `\let`s it to `\@centercr`) which leads to an endless loop which TeX eventually detects (by an exceeded input stack).

I'm *very* reluctant to try to adapt `ragged2e` to `picinpar` (or to even spend more time on this) - IMHO `picinpar` is simply to old and the problem it tries to solve should be solved by a new (LaTeX3?) package.

Comment: if you look at its position on the archive, you’ll see that `picinpar` is in the latex209 area.  iirc it’s been patched to make it _“mostly”_ work with 2e, but i guess that expecting it to work with _bidi_ text is optimism stretched to its limits.  there are several alternatives in the [catalogue]( http://www.ctan.org/topic/) — search key `text-flow`

Comment: It may be slightly off topic, but I tried some alternatives to picinpar and was left with this as the best implementation right now. If there are better suggestions, I would love some. All it needs is to have images on the right side with text wrapped around them, without overlapping the images. And no captions.

WrapFig specifically had several issues with multiple images, and text running over the image.

Answer (score 4):

You should enclose `\RaggedLeft نلي بلانت السياحي.` in braces to get it work.

```
{\RaggedLeft نلي بلانت السياحي.}
```

In fact, this works

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\begin{tabwindow}[0,r,{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}\includegraphics[width=0.28
\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}},{ \ }] {\RaggedLeft نلي بلانت السياحي.} \\[\baselineskip]
\end{tabwindow}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've used enclosing things in brackets elsewhere several times, but it didn't cross my mind to use here.

Comment: Actually, unfortunately after testing, I noticed this didn't actually fix my issue. It takes out the error yes, but unfortunately the test is NOT right aligned anymore. It appears that adding braces around the \RaggedLeft command makes it apply to none of the actual text.